# Cakephp select box remove one of the item if it's the same name

Tags: php, html, cakephp, drop-down-menu, cakephp-2.0

I have a query like this:

```
$customerList = $this->Project->Contact->find('list', array(
   'fields' => array('Contact.id', 'Contact.displayName', 'Contact.companyName'),
    'conditions' => array(
          'Contact.group_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'),
          'Contact.company_id !=' => 0,
          'Contact.deleted NOT' => 1
    ),
    'order' => 'Contact.companyName ASC'
));
```

if I debug it, it will show something like this

```
array(
    'Bosiang Ramli' => array(
        (int) 90 => 'Bosiang Ramli'
    ),
    'Harts Ramli' => array(
        (int) 61 => 'Harts Ramli',
        (int) 67 => 'Kayoko Bishop',
        (int) 77 => 'Sintia Mary'
    ),
    'Microsoft' => array(
        (int) 83 => 'Internet Explorer',
        (int) 84 => 'Windows Eight',
        (int) 85 => 'X Box',
        (int) 86 => 'Windows Phone'
    ),
    'NySoft' => array(
        (int) 82 => 'Norman Leonardi'
    ),
    'Q Continuum' => array(
        (int) 81 => 'Andrew Stewart',
        (int) 87 => 'Jack Esters',
        (int) 88 => 'Ron Swanson',
        (int) 89 => 'Susan Mitchels'
    )
)
```

how come when I put it into a form

```
echo $this->Form->input('contact_id',   
          array('label' => 'Customer', 'options' => $customerList)
);
```

It will remove the option for Bosiang Ramli, and Harts Ramli as an option?
I will show the picture.
[image]

What's the problem here? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to add

```
'showParents' => true
```

as one of the params